# Why it won't throw an error when the shape of parameter is different from that of argument in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Here are the codes:

```
function a(fn: (a: string) => void) {
  fn("Hello, World");
} 
a(function b() {
  return 1
});
```

By adding the type annotation to the callback of function `a`, it means function `a` must receive a function which has a argument of type `string` and a return value of type `void`. But when I passed function `b` which couldn't satisfy the conditions of the type annotation, TS still didn't throw an compile error. Why?

Also, when I changed the value passed to `fn` from `"Hello, world"`(`string`) to `123`(`number`), it did throw an error. In this case, the type annotation worked.

Comment: b *can* take a string parameter, and given that its output isn't used it's irrelevant if it has any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things here:

[Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)

and

[Why are functions returning non-void assignable to function returning void?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void)

The two links above are from the Typescript FAQ, and it should give you clarity about the said behaviour. Bottomline, this is expected outcome of the following two logical conclusions:

1. The function that you are passing as the callback should be allowed to NOT use the parameter `a` of string type.
2. Returning more information when expected is none, that is `void`, is fine.

So, this won't work, because function `b` expects a number while `a` would pass a string.

```js
// Argument of type '(p: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: string) => void'.
//  Types of parameters 'p' and 'a' are incompatible.
//    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number
a(function b(p: number) {
  return 1
});
```

But this will work because `b` has no use of string that function `a` will pass to it... and it should be fine.

```js
a(function b() {
  return 1
});
```

Here is the link to TS Playground: https://tsplay.dev/WyObJN

```js
function a(fn: (a: string) => void) {
  fn("Hello, World");
} 


a(function b() {
  return 1
});


// Argument of type '(p: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: string) => void'.
//  Types of parameters 'p' and 'a' are incompatible.
//    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number
a(function b(p: number) {
  return 1
});


function a1(fn: (a: string) => number) {
  fn("Hello, World");
} 

// Argument of type '(p: string) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: string) => number'.
//  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2345)
a1(function b(p: string) {
  return p;
});
```

So, shape mismatch in callback function will only work if the callback passed is *compatible* with the callback parameter.

Comment: It seems this question is about function compatibility. But according to its definition, we can treat b as a subtype of a only when the type of b's return value is a subtype of that of a's return value. However in this case, type number isn't the subtype of type void. So I'm confused about the compatibility of the types of return value

Comment: A better way to think about it as a contract. Function `a` takes a function `fn` which will be provided with a parameter of type `string` and `fn` isn't expected to return anything. If you pass a function that does not need the `string` parameter and that returns something, is fine. What's not fine is, a function passed that required a parameter that's not a subtype of `string`. And, if `fn` was returning something, and the passed function doesn't return that type or subtype. @Chor

Answer (score 2):

Consider this simple example:

```js
type StringToVoid = (a: string) => void
type VoidToNumber = () => number

declare let a: StringToVoid
declare let b: VoidToNumber

a = b // ok
b = a // error
```

It is almost safe to assign `b` to `a`, just like in your example. Treat `b` as a subtype of `a`. Nothing bad happens if :

```js
a=b;
// a is b
const result = a('str') // void, but in fact number
```

If you provide an argument to a function which is not expect any arguments, it does not affect your logic.
Same for return type. Function `a` does not return anything. Hence you can't use it. If you assign `b` to `a` it return a value but TS will not allow you to do smth with it.

Whereas it is not safe to assign `a` to `b` since `a` expect an argument which may lead to runtime error

```js
b = a

b().toFixed(10) // runtime error
```

Comment: It seems this question is about function compatibility. But according to its definition, we can treat `b` as a subtype of `a` only when the type of `b`'s return value is a subtype of that of `a`'s return value. However in this case, type `number` isn't the subtype of type `void`. So I'm confused about the compatibility of the types of return value.

Comment: @Chor I was not clear enough when I wrote `treat it as a subtype`, in fact it is `a valid substitution`

Comment: Yes. According to TS FAQ, it is called `substitution`. But calling it `subtype` is also OK.